# Is there a NuGet API to mark an existing package as "Deprecated"?

Tags: nuget

I'm using the `NuGet.Protocol` package to query information about my packages on nuget.org, with the goal being to mark certain versions as deprecated.

At the moment, the only way I know how to do that is via the NuGet.org web UI, but I'm trying to automate this (recurring) task.

Is there a mechanism using the NuGet API to mark a specific package version as deprecated? I've searched high and low through the NuGet code repo and haven't seen anything that looks likely.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [NuGet Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview) doesn't have any API to mark a package as deprecated, so there's no way for the official client (or client SDK, of which `NuGet.Protocol` is part of) to do it.